# Insert a list to postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert a list of values to a Postgres table through Python:

The values are in a list say:

```
new=
[
    [gold, dresden, 1000, 24],
    [silver, Cologne, 600, 42],
    [gold, Aachen, 3000, 25]
]
```

And the table has already been created in Postgres with the headers. How do I do the insertion?

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO B4_O (position, city, amount, score) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", new)
db.commit
```

But this gives me error:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: `for item in new: ...` and `db.execute(..., item)` or try `new[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [psycopg2.extras.execute_values()](http://psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values):

```
new = [
    ['gold', 'dresden', 1000, 24],
    ['silver', 'Cologne', 600, 42],
    ['gold', 'Aachen', 3000, 25]
]

from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

execute_values(db, "INSERT INTO B4_O (position, city, amount, score) VALUES %s", new)
```

Answer (score 1):

The interface `db.execute()` you are using is executing a SQL INSERT command. You can refer to [the relevant documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html); you need a string of the form

```
INSERT INTO B4_O (position, city, amount, score) 
       VALUES ("gold", "dresden", 1000, 24),
              ("silver", "Cologne", 600, 42),
              ("gold", "Aachen", 3000, 25)
```

A simple way to get the values in python is:

```
','.join(['("{}", "{}", {}, {})'.format(*x) for x in new])
```

Note that some python lib like [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args) support multiple rows insertion out of the box.